# Java: How do I optimize memory footprint of reading/updating/writing many little files?

Tags: java, optimization, file-io, garbage-collection

I need to improve an open source tool (Releng) (with JDK 1.5 compliance) that updates copyright headers in source files. (e.g copyright 2000, 2011).

It reads files and inserts back a newer revision date (e.g 2014).

Currently it eats so much memory that performance slows down to a crawl. 
I need to re-write the file parser so that it uses less memory/runs faster.

I've written a basic file parser (below) that reads all files in a directory (project/files). It then increment's the first four digits found in the file and prints run-time information.

[edit]
On a small scale the current result performs 25 garbage collections and garbage collection takes 12 ms. On a large scale I get so much memory overhead that GC thrashes performance.

```
Runs     Time(ms) avrg(ms)  GC_count   GC_time
200      4096     20        25         12
200      4158     20        25         12
200      4072     20        25         12
200      4169     20        25         13
```

Is it possible to re-use File or String objects (and other objects??) to reduce garbage collection count?

Optimization guides suggest re-using objects. 
I have considered using Stringbuilder instead of Strings. But from what I gather, it's only useful if you do a lot of concatenation. Which is not done in this case?
I also don't know how to re-use any other objects in the code below (e.g files?)?

How can I go about re-using objects in this scenario (or optimize the code below)?

Any ideas/suggestions are welcomed.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.GarbageCollectorMXBean;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Test {

    //Use Bash script to create 2000 files, each having a 4 digit number.
     /*
      #!/bin/sh
      rm files/test*
      for i in {1..2000}
      do
      echo "2000" > files/test$i
      done
     */

    /*
     * Example output:
     * runs: 200
     * Run time: 4822 average: 24
     * Gc runs: Total Garbage Collections: 28
     * Total Garbage Collection Time (ms): 17
     */

    private static String filesPath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/files";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final File folder = new File(filesPath);

        ArrayList<String> paths = listFilesForFolder(folder);
        if (paths == null) {
            System.out.println("no files found");
            return;
        }


        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // ..
        // your code
        int runs = 200;
        System.out.println("Run: ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= runs; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
            updateFiles(paths);
        }
        System.out.println("");

        // ..
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long runtime = end - start;
        System.out.println("Runs     Time     avrg      GC_count   GC_time");
        System.out.println(runs + "      " + Long.toString(runtime) + "     " + (runtime / runs) + "       " + printGCStats());

    }

    private static ArrayList<String> listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                paths.add(filesPath + "/" + fileEntry.getName());
            }
        }
        if (paths.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return paths;
        }
    }

    private static void updateFiles(final ArrayList<String> paths) {
        for (String path : paths) {
            try {
                String content = readFile(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                int year = Integer.parseInt(content.substring(0, 4));
                year++;
                Files.write(Paths.get(path), Integer.toString(year).getBytes(),
                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Failed to read: " + path);
            }
        }
    }

    static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)); // closes file.
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    //PROFILING HELPER
    public static String printGCStats() {
        long totalGarbageCollections = 0;
        long garbageCollectionTime = 0;
        for (GarbageCollectorMXBean gc : ManagementFactory.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans()) {
            long count = gc.getCollectionCount();

            if (count >= 0) {
                totalGarbageCollections += count;
            }
            long time = gc.getCollectionTime();
            if (time >= 0) {
                garbageCollectionTime += time;
            }
        }
        return " " + totalGarbageCollections + "         " + garbageCollectionTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to read every file fully into memory for this purpose. You should explore using java.io.FileInputStream#getChannel to make your edits. This will avoid the memory pressure you are seeing.

Comment: A non-helping side note: Replacing an empty list by `null` is a terrible antipattern, which leads to more code or an NPE in `for (String path : paths)`. Btw., you data look like you're spending 12 out of 4000 millisecond in GC, so why care? However, you can save yourself quite some overhead when working with byte arrays instead of strings.

Comment: It works ok on a small scale. Once I get to 20k or 100k files the GC time kills performance.  Thank you for the byte array tip, I'll try.  Thank you for NPE tip, I'll fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the code above actually works fine.

I found that in the production code, the code didn't close a file buffer which caused a memory leak which caused performance issues with larger amounts of files.

After that was fixed, it scaled well.